# Xcode How to detect when a childview within scrollview is opened

Tags: swift, xcode, scrollview, avplayer

I have a viewcontroller with a scrollview inside it. I have three child  viewcontrollers linked to this scrollview. In one of the child viewcontrollers, I want to start playing videos with AVPlayer when the user swipes to that view.

Currently with my code, begins the video when the scrollview is loaded even when I am not in that childview.

I have tried calling the download method in viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    download()

}

func download() {

    let fireStoreRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("")

    fireStoreRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot{

            for document in snapshot.documents{

                let stringURL = document.get("videoURL")

                if stringURL != nil {
                    let videoURL = URL(string: stringURL as! String)
                    self.videoURLs.append(videoURL!)
                }

            }

            self.play(url: self.videoURLs[0])

        }
    }
}

func play(url: URL) {

    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player.play()
}
```

Would like the AVplayer to begin playing when user swipes to specific childview of scrollview

Comment: Try implementing the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol in your controller class. It has various methods that are sent to the controller to communicate the ScrollView's current state to the controller class, e.g. `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(UIScrollView)`. You could implement this function in such a way to compare the position of your child view controller with the current position of the scroll view, perhaps...  Try reading the docs and writing some code. Come back here and post it if you're having difficulty with your proposed solution!